# Jquery UI slider inconsistent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem with this jquery UI Slider not showing the label of the selected option properly. The slider (with my current code below) is at first displaying the first option, which is what I'd expect, but after using the slider to select another option, then going back to the first, it displays as the second array option rather than the first.

It also is not showing all of the options in one clear swipe; instead, it shows the first three array strings, then stops, then when you go back an option, it shows the fourth, and final string from the array. I've been playing around with it for the past hour, but haven't gotten to any solution. Is there any way I can fix this?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<style type="text/css">
#slider {
width: 300px;
}
#itemlabel {
text-align: center;
}
</style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var valMap = [1.5, 2.5, 5.5, 10.5];
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {                        
            $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")] + '0');            
        }       
    });
    $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")] + '0');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center><div id="planlabel"><p>
  <label for="amount">Item:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p></div>
<div id="slider"></div></center>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change "slide" to "change".

```
$(function() {
    var valMap = [1.5, 2.5, 5.5, 10.5];
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        value: 0,
        change: function(event, ui) {                        
            $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")] + '0');
        }       
    });
    $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")] + '0');
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/GmCt9/)

The "change" callback is called after the value of the slider changes, while the "slide" callback is called for mouse movements, but it may be before the value changes.

And although the slider documentation doesn't state it, I believe you can shorted the one line inside the callback to:

```
$("#amount").val('$' + valMap[ui.value] + '0');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks; that's exactly what I was looking for!

Edit: Thanks for the shortened bit too!

Comment: Another option would be, if you want it to update as you slide, is to use the slide callback, but get the value via `ui.value` ( http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide).